# Why is R script running slower on Windows Server 2008 than OSX 10.6?

Tags: windows, r, performance, macos

I'm have migrated some scripts from an old iMac running OS X 10.6.8 with 4GB Ram and a 2.53GHz Core 2 Duo processor (circ 2008) to a new virtual AWS machine running Windows Server 2008, 64-bit with with 15GB of memory. Despite this the following code is taking 4 times as long to run on the new Windows machine.

I have changed some surrounding code, but this section which is the bottle neck, is identical. The input variable (`unique_dates`, `summary_data`, `in_data`) are also of a similar size between the two machines.

On the Windows machine it takes almost 30 seconds for each `date` cycle compared to 5 seconds previously on the Mac.

Any suggestions on how to speed this up would be greatly appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

From the comments being made I'm getting the impression that there is a much faster way of doing this without the loops which my render the original question a moot point.

I'm trying to achieve the following:
I have a time series of data for a number of companies. For each date, each company has a 1mth, 3mth, 6mth, 12mth, 18mth and 24mth return. Each company is also assigned to a group (fractile). For each date I would like to calculate the mean and median 1mth, 3mth, 6mth etc. returns for each fractile.

The results are then stored in the `summary_data` data frame which is pre-allocated.

The actual data has 343 dates, 500 companies for each date and 25 companies to a fractile. The slowest part is the `ss_in_data <- subset(in_data, ...)` which takes almost a second compared to the rest which in total is about 0.02sec.

I'm fairly new to R, but in MYSQL I could calculate this pretty simply using `MEAN` and `GROUP BY DATE, FRACTILE`. Is there a similar way of doing this in R?

Thanks again for all the help.

My current code is below the sample data:

```
# In this sample data there are 12 companies, 3 dates. Each company is 
# assigned to 1 of 3 fractiles
# Consequently there are 4 companies in each fractile.

# Create input data
date1 <- as.Date(as.character('2010-01-31'),"%Y-%m-%d")
date2 <- as.Date(as.character('2010-02-28'),"%Y-%m-%d")
date3 <- as.Date(as.character('2010-03-31'),"%Y-%m-%d")

dates <- c(rep(date1,12),rep(date2,12),rep(date3,12))

coys <- rep(c('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L'),3)
ret_3mth <- rep(seq(0.1, by=0.2, length.out = 12),3)
ret_6mth <- rep(seq(0.2, by=0.2, length.out = 12),3)
ret_12mth <- rep(seq(0.3, by=0.2, length.out = 12),3)
fractiles <- rep(rep(c(1,2,3),4),3)

in_data <- data.frame(dates, coys, ret_3mth, ret_6mth, ret_12mth, fractiles)

# Initialise summary data frame
dates <- c(rep(date1,3),rep(date2,3),rep(date3,3))
fractiles <- rep(c(1,2,3),3)
mean_3mth <- rep(NA,9)
mean_6mth <- rep(NA,9)
mean_12mth <- rep(NA,9)
summary <- data.frame(dates, fractiles, mean_3mth, mean_6mth, mean_12mth)

# Other variables
unique_dates <- unique(dates)
num_fract_curr <- 3
```

Current method:

```
for (date in unique_dates) {
      # Only write to screen ever x loops (as set by write_line_freq)
      if (counter%%write_line_freq == 0) {
        writeLines(paste(run_name,' : Summary calcs ROCE ',roce, '  Date: ',as.Date(date, origin='1970-01-01'),
                         ' ',counter,':',num_dates,'  Time: ',format.timediff(start_time),sep=''))
      }
      counter <- counter + 1


  for(i in 1:num_fract_curr) {
    # Create subsets to speed up processing

    ss_summary_data <- subset(summary_data, date_base == as.Date(date, origin='1970-01-01') & summary_data[summary_data_fractile] == i)
    ss_in_data <- subset(in_data, date_base == as.Date(date, origin='1970-01-01') & in_data[in_data_fractile] == i)


    # Causes error if ss_in_data is empty
    if (nrow(ss_in_data) > 0) {
      ss_summary_data$mean1mth <- mean(ss_in_data$ret_1mth, na.rm = TRUE)
      ss_summary_data$median1mth <- median(ss_in_data$ret_1mth, na.rm = TRUE)

      ss_summary_data$mean3mth <- mean(ss_in_data$ret_3mth, na.rm = TRUE)
      ss_summary_data$median3mth <- median(ss_in_data$ret_3mth, na.rm = TRUE)

      ss_summary_data$mean6mth <- mean(ss_in_data$ret_6mth, na.rm = TRUE)
      ss_summary_data$median6mth <- median(ss_in_data$ret_6mth, na.rm = TRUE)

      ss_summary_data$mean12mth <- mean(ss_in_data$ret_12mth, na.rm = TRUE)
      ss_summary_data$median12mth <- median(ss_in_data$ret_12mth, na.rm = TRUE)

      ss_summary_data$mean18mth <- mean(ss_in_data$ret_18mth, na.rm = TRUE)
      ss_summary_data$median18mth <- median(ss_in_data$ret_18mth, na.rm = TRUE)

      ss_summary_data$mean24mth <- mean(ss_in_data$ret_24mth, na.rm = TRUE)
      ss_summary_data$median24mth <- median(ss_in_data$ret_24mth, na.rm = TRUE)

      # Save the updated summary data back into the 'summary_data' data frame
      summary_data[(summary_data$date == date) & (summary_data[summary_data_fractile] == i),] <- ss_summary_data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume that you preallocate `ss_summary_data` to the correct size? If not, this is an obvious improvement which will improve speed by orders of magnitude.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra No, I haven't preallocated `ss_summary_data` at all. As a `data.frame` I didn't realise you should or even could do that. The first time it's referenced or defined is in the code you see. Same with `ss_in_data`, it's defined in this code. Should they both be preallocated? They aren't large though, max 50 rows.

Comment: Ok, max 50 rows doesn't sound like that would pose a bottleneck. Sequentially growing an object is notoriously slow in R, but of course only for building larger objects that one with 50 rows.

Comment: Nothing is being built sequentially. `ss_summary_data` is recreated/overwritten each cycle as a subset of `summary_data` and then written back into `summary_data` which is already created so it's not changing in size.

Comment: It's not easy to understand from the code what you are trying to do there exactly, but if I don't miss something, you shouldn't need `for` loops. It looks like you are trying to reinvent the "split-apply-combine" approach. Have a look at packages plyr, dplyr or data.table.

Comment: If you provided a small sample data set, it would be easier to show you how much faster this could be. Your data structure, which has one column per `ret_mth`, is probably not ideal. Looping through each date is also not ideal. Using one of the methods suggested by @Roland would likely speed this up so much that the difference between Mac and Windows wouldn't even matter.

Comment: A reproducible example is needed here for any kind of advice on performance. That's why you've got lot's of comments and no answers.

Comment: I think this might have a lot to do with the problem:  new **virtual** AWS machine

Comment: @Roland: Thanks for your suggestion to use ddplyr. Problem solved with computation time reduced from 12 hours to a few seconds. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get to the bottom of the speed difference, but this is a ridiculous method of performing this calculation in R.

Instead use `ddply` as suggested by @Roland.

Computation time was reduced from 12 hours to a few seconds.

Thanks everyone for your assistance.

New method:

```
 summary_data <- ddply(in_data, c('date_base',fractile_name),summarise, mean_1mth = mean(ret_1mth, na.rm=TRUE), 
                                          mean_3mth = mean(ret_3mth, na.rm=TRUE),mean_6mth = mean(ret_6mth, na.rm=TRUE),
                                          mean_12mth = mean(ret_12mth, na.rm=TRUE), mean_18mth = mean(ret_18mth, na.rm=TRUE),
                                          mean_24mth = mean(ret_24mth, na.rm=TRUE),
                                          median_1mth = median(ret_1mth, na.rm=TRUE), median_3mth = median(ret_3mth, na.rm=TRUE),
                                          median_6mth = median(ret_6mth, na.rm=TRUE), median_12mth = median(ret_12mth, na.rm=TRUE), 
                                          median_18mth = median(ret_18mth, na.rm=TRUE),median_24mth = median(ret_24mth, na.rm=TRUE))
```